# How to maintain sqlite newlines in php

Tags: php, sqlite, search

I managed to get newlines into my sqlite database using quotes around my column entries

> "start
>
> end"

but when I query it in php all of my newlines vanish!

`start end`

How can I maintain my newlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**nl2br**

php documentation for [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) states:

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

with an example:

> Example #1 Using nl2br()
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> foo isn't<br />
>  bar
> ```

just add **nl2br** after your echo: `echo nl2br(.....);`

Comment: Use code markup, not quotations, for code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You've been here for 2 years, how could you not know how to format code in answers?